# Nexus 1.9.1.1 - How to avoid empty archetype-catalogs?

Tags: nexus

I have a number of hosted and proxy repositories carried in my Nexus 1.9.1.1 instance.

From what I have read, re-indexing ("Update Index") should generate the archetype-catalog.xml file with the proper contents.

No matter what though, my archetype-catalog.xml's continue to be essentially "0-sized" (they have the xml headers, etc, but no archetypes.)

In one particular case, where I am proxying another repo and that repo has a plus-sized archetype-catalog, mine continues to show 0 elements.

Adoption of the centralized repo is taking heat because other developers can't create projects using their favorite archetypes.  Any thoughts?

Thanks!
-Lorin

Comment: I'm having the same trouble but only on windows machines. On linux machines it is working fine. I have no idea why...

Answer (score 2):

Change the pom.xml for the archetype so that it has:

```
<packaging>maven-archetype</packaging>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Croesus's answer is a step in the right direction, but a more complete solution is described in the [Maven archetype documentation](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/archetype-packaging/).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm getting the following error message: "The current project does not built an archetype". Any ideas how to fix that?